# Roles and membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

when the user logon, I want to check the roles he belong to, and according to that customize a select statement with roles for example:

if the user have a role of toyota and ford : the sql statement will be:

```
select * from issues where provider = 'toyota' and provider = 'ford'
```

With a dropdownlist that will be also populated with toyota and ford, so the user can only view and modify the rows that he is allowed to.

I don't know how to implement this logic, please help

PS: sorry for my english, I'm a french speaker :) .

Comment: Please format your posting.

Comment: please show the TABLE struscture for USER and ISSSUES ..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provider may have two different values ​​at the same time? I do not think so.

Use the "join table" user_provider. Sorry for the pseudo-code.

```
Users
UserId 1 Name Paul
UserId 2 Name Carl
UserId 3 Name Volume

Providers
ProviderId 1 Name Toyota
ProviderId 2 Name Honda
ProviderId 3 Name Ford

User_Provider
ProviderId 1 UserId 1
ProviderId 1 UserId 2
ProviderId 2 UserId 3
ProviderId 3 UserId 1
ProviderId 3 UserId 2

select * from issues where providerId in (select ProviderId from user_provider where UserId = 1)
```

In that case, Paul is our man with Toyota and Ford.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to update the poste with an image of my table structre, but it tells me that I need reputation ...

Comment: Yes a user can have access to different providers if he has multiple roles (authorization)

Comment: To clarify my question, I'll ask another way: : how can I allow a user to access a certain view of a table according to his roles.

Comment: If I understand, you want to share the content if the user belongs to a group, such as Ford, Toyota. In this case - what I wrote should work for you.

Displayed to him content contains `provider = fort` and content with `provider = toyota` (i mean - 2 different contents)

If we still do not understand each other, please use the example.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want. 
For example the query result for paul, will be a view with all rows related to ford and Toyota.

Comment: In that case - please select my answer as correct.
Glad I could help.

Comment: In the example above the Ford providerID should be 3 (I couldn't edit because it's just one character)

Answer (score 0):

`provider = 'toyota' and provider = 'ford'` will always be false, because the provider can't be both at the same time.
Use `or` instead of `and`:

```
select * from issues where provider = 'toyota' or provider = 'ford'
```